# Logging into a hidden user account on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts

I created a hidden user account and disabled it from the Windows login screen and Fast User Switch menu using reg command

```
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\SpecialAccounts\Userlist" /v user /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
```

but how can i login into this user now?

Answer (score 2):

To login into a hidden account, you need to
[make Windows ask for user name and password during log on](https://winaero.com/blog/how-to-make-windows-10-ask-for-user-name-and-password-during-log-on/).

In the Local Security Policy (`secpol.msc`), go to *Local Policies > Security options*
and enable "Interactive logon: Don't display last user name".

Answer (score 1):

You need to unhide it if you want to login to it. The only other form of login that won't require unhide is the runas command.

Answer (score 0):

The funny story is that I hid administrator account in Windows 10, depriving myself of access to this account, so generally it is unwise to do this, because it works also in case of permission elevation prompt! The solution I found is to boot a system from USB and edit the registry. I used Debian and chntpw tool: https://mashtips.com/how-to-edit-the-windows-registry-using-ubuntu/